# How to disable dialog boxes - alert()?

Tags: javascript, iframe, alert

I have a page where I'm displaying iframes. The iframes are on the same domain with the website so I can edit and read the content of it, but I can't edit the source code of the iframes, because I don't have access to the file itself. 
The iframes are alerting a message and I want to disable this.
I want to disable the dialog boxes at least for myself, I`m using chrome...

Is this possible without disabling javascript ?
Or could I disable javascript only inside the iframes ?

Answer (score 7):

What about:

```
window.frames[0].alert = function() {};
```

It overwrites the alert function inside the first iframe with a function that does nothing, hence all `alert(...)` calls called there result in nothing happening.

As for subsequent iframes, you'd need to change `0` into `1` etc.