# Disabling javascript alerts from iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, iframe

I have an `iFrame` inside my `HTML` code.

This iFrame has a javascript that shows `Window.alert()` popups.

How can I prevent them from appearing? and also prevent the iFrame from interacting with my window?

I'm using `GWT`'s `Frame` If that's relevent.

== EDIT ==

The iFrame is not in the same domain as my website so i can't access the Javascript code from the iFrame

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672849/how-to-disable-dialog-boxes-alert)

Comment: In the other question `The iframes are on the same domain with the website` I edited my question thanks you for pointing that out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is a bit late, but I have an improvement to philfreo's answer. Iframe sandbox has an `allow-popups` attribute you can exclude. Try this: `<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin" src="..."></iframe>`

Answer (score 6):

For browsers that support the `sandbox` attribute on `<iframe>`s, you can disable ALL JavaScript (including `alerts`).

```
<iframe sandbox src="..."></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

As your iframe is not in the same domain, it's impossible to script it (and remove the alert) because of the [Same origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

I'm sorry, but that's the answer

Cheers

Comment: it turned out that you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage in order to pass messages between iFrames in cross-domain. But you'll need to own both domains though.

Comment: This answer is no longer true, check answer from: Robert Moore

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve you issue.
So I found a way to help you.
Here is my way.

```
document.getElementById('iframe-src').contentWindow.alert = function(){}
```

And this way worked well.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**sandbox** attribute will help you to block alert() from iframe

```
<iframe sandbox src="..."></iframe>
```