# Hide confirm box in iframe src and send a 'no' response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

In my parent.html, I have an iframe element

```
<iframe src="child.html"></iframe>
```

There is a JS function in my child.html:

```
<script>
  if (confirm("Would you like to do this?")){
                <!--Some function-->
            }
            else{
                <!--wanted function-->
            }
</script>
```

I want to avoid showing confirm box to the user and go into the else loop(equivalent to click of 'no' in the confirm box). Is there a way in JS/jQuery to do that from parent.html?

Note: I can't edit anything in the child.html

Comment: No, there is no "way in JS/jQuery to do that from parent.html", short of requesting the content of child.html (same domain?) parsing it, replacing `confirm` with `true` and writing it to the frame.

Comment: You could try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6749348/1022914). while replacing `window.frames[0].alert` with `window.frames[0].confim`. Though, I think `child.html` has to be on the same domain.

Comment: @Mikey that worked... Thanks... :)